# Find the length of the path $\gamma(t)=t-ie^{-it}$, $0 \leq t \leq 2$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the length of the path $\gamma(t)=t-ie^{-it}$, $0 \leq t \leq 2$.

I basically think that
$$\begin{aligned}
length(\gamma)&＝\int^2_0|\gamma'(t)|dt\\
& =\int^2_0\left|1-e^{-it}\right|dt\\
& =\int^2_0\left|1-(\cos t-i\sin t)\right|dt\\
& =\int^2_0\sqrt{(1-\cos t)^2+\sin^2 t}dt\\
& =\int^2_0\sqrt{2-2\cos t} dt\\
& =\int^2_0\sqrt{2(1-1+2\sin^2\frac{t}{2})} dt\\
& = 2 \int^2_0\left|\sin \frac{t}{2}\right|dt\\
& =4\int^2_0\left|\sin \frac{t}{2}\right|d\frac{t}{2}\\
\left(\text{ let }x=\frac{t}{2} \right) & =4 \int^1_0\left|\sin x\right|dx\\
& =4 \int^1_0 \sin x dx\\
& =-4 \cos x |^1_0=-4(\cos 1-1)=4-4\cos 1
\end{aligned}$$
However, the solution gives
$$\sqrt{17}+\frac{1}{4}\sinh^{-1}(4)$$
Could anyone help me to look at this? Thanks~

Comment: If we consider $\gamma$ a curve, then your answer appears to be correct (I integrated with *Mathematica* which confirms your answer).

Comment: @Myridium Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expressed the solution as follows:

$$
z=t-ie^{it}\\
\dot z=1-i^2e^{it}=1+e^{it}\\
\dot z=1+\cos(t)+i\sin t\\
|\dot z|=\sqrt{2+2\cos t}\\
s=\int_0^2 |\dot z|dt=2\sqrt{2+2\cos t}+\tan\frac{t}{2}\biggr|_0^2\approx3.3659
$$

I have verified this result numerically. The other result you presented does not give the same answer.